# Copying everything from one table to another - Change a value, and have an auto incrementing ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to copy the entire contents of "TableA" to "TableB"... but with a few catches, first off, Table B needs to have all new auto incrementing IDs (I have it set as a BIGINT, and it auto increments in the schema), then I need the value of "refereceID" in TableB to always have the "id" value of that row in TableA. Third, there is a "report" field, and for now - I would like it to ALWAYS have the value of '1'.

Here is my current SQL :

```
INSERT into tableB(id, report, referenceID, address, zip, last_seen_on, created) 
VALUES( 
    ,1
    ,[id] 
    ,[address] 
    ,[zip] 
    ,[last_seen_on] 
    ,[created])
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

But I keep getting an SQL error which looks like this :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 1, [id], [address], [zip], [last_seen_on], [created] ' at line 11

Comment: Your field delimiters indicate you are not working with MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need (note this syntax is for SQL, missed the MySQL part, but should be very similar/the same for MySQL)

```
    INSERT into tableB(report, referenceID, address, zip, last_seen_on, created) 
Select         1
        ,[id] 
        ,[address] 
        ,[zip] 
        ,[last_seen_on] 
        ,[created]
from TableA
```

Your insert has more columns then your values (if id is the auto increment value in your Insert statement, you should be able to leave that off).

Comment: So then, do I also remove the 'id' from the INSERT into line? That comma is supposed to be denoting that the '1' is to be used for the value of "Report" not id.

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds yes, autoid columns do not get specified in the insert into line so removing that should make your syntax work.

Comment: Nevermind - your syntax and suggestion worked as soon as I dropped the square brackets :)